# Can I use Map here rather than Table?

Tags: map

I've got something that works, but it seems like it would be "nicer" if I didn't have to use Table (or For, etc.).

I've got 3 Excel files, each with multiple sheets.  Each file also has a sheet called "Paste Here" that I don't want.  Each sheet contains an array.  I'm reading in the file names from the folder, then from each file I read in the sheet names.

Now, I'd like to read the array from each sheet and store them all in a single (nested) list.  I'm currently doing the following, which works fine:

```
Module[{pmlPath},
pmlPath = ParentDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]] <> pmlFolder;
fileNames = Select[FileNames["*.xlsm", pmlPath], StringCount[#, "~"] == 0 &];
sheetNames = DeleteCases[(Import[#, "Sheets"] & /@ fileNames), "Paste Here", {2}];
pmls = Table[Import[fileNames[[i]], 
       {"Sheets", sheetNames[[i, j]]}], {i,Length[fileNames]}, {j,Length[sheetNames[[i]]]}];
];
```

It seems like I would have to use multiple slots to accomplish that, if it's possible, and I really don't know how to do that.

Comment: Maybe something like `Import[#, {"Sheets", #2}] & @@@ Transpose[{fileNames, sheetNames}]`?

Comment: Or `Import[#1, {"Sheets", #2}] & ~MapThread~ {fileNames, sheetNames}`

Comment: Okay, I'll toss in: `Inner[Import[#, {"Sheets", #2}] &, fileNames, sheetNames, List]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fileNames = "file" <> # & /@ RandomSample[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], 4]

(* {"fileS","fileU","fileJ","fileO"} *)

sheetNames = "sheet" <> # & /@ # & /@ (RandomSample[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], 
                                            RandomInteger[{1, 3}]] & /@ Range[4])

(* {{"sheetB","sheetR","sheetK"},{"sheetA"},{"sheetC","sheetO","sheetW"}, 
    {"sheetY","sheetU"}}*)
```

Use `Import` in place of `foo` in the following:

```
foo[#, {"Sheets", #2}] & @@@ Transpose[{fileNames, sheetNames}]

(* {foo["fileS",{"Sheets",{"sheetB","sheetR","sheetK"}}],
    foo["fileU",{"Sheets",{"sheetA"}}],
    foo["fileJ",{"Sheets",{"sheetC","sheetO","sheetW"}}],
    foo["fileO",{"Sheets",{"sheetY","sheetU"}}]} *)
```

Comment: I don't understand the second "# & /@".   I see that it doesn't work if I remove it.  Denote "(RandomSample[CharacterRange" and everything to it's right as X.  If I execute X, I get the same thing as when I execute # & /@ X.  I really don't understand what's happening.

Comment: @MitchellKaplan, the function `f="sheet"<>#&` concatenates "sheet" with the input argument. (Btw you can get the same result using `Map["sheet" <> # &, X, {2}]` -- map `f` on `X` at level 2.)  If you compare the outputs of `f/@X` and `f/@#&/@X`, you see that, when `X` is a list of lists, the first one applies `f` to the rows of `X` while the second applies it to the deeper elements inside each sublist. Hope this helps.